# How do the size standard libraries compare for different languages

Tags: frameworks, standard-library, lines-of-code, code-size

Someone was recently raving about how great jQuery was and how it made javascript into a pleasure and also how the whole source code was so small(and one file).

I looked it up on www.ohloh.net/ and it said it was about 30,000 lines of javascript, when I tired curl piped to wc it said about 5000 lines(strange discrepancy that, maybe test suites, etc?).

I thought well it isn't that strange since javascript from what I've heard has a lot of fun dynamic tricks, so you can probably get away with a small library.

But then I thought what about other high level languages, the ones with large standard libraries and wondered how big the standard are for python/ruby/haskell/pharo(smalltalk)/*ml/etc. (libraries not vm stuff to the degree its possible to separate it)

Anybody know? Any details (comment/blank/code lines , test code lines, lines in language vs lines in ffi/byte-code) are appreciated!

**edit: ps. since it started this me asking about jQuery as a bonus if you could please list the size of mega frameworks, a megaframewok provides so much that people using an x megaframework in language y might sometimes refer to programming in xy or even x rather then in y (ie. : qt, jQuery, etc.).**

Comment: There's a readable version of jQuery for maintenance, and a minified version for deploying, to reduce the download size. That could explain the discrepancy.

Comment: jQuery and, say, Python have vastly different purposes, environments and scope. It might be kinda cool to know the weight ratio between a battleship and a Volkswagen Beetle, but it isn't a particularly _useful_ number.

Comment: note 5000 lines of code was for the non minified version.

Comment: i know they have a very large non overlapping purpose, but I would still like to know.

Comment: Using Python as an example, a lot of the Python "standard libraries" (time, os, sys) are largely just wrappers around standard C library functions, and other "standard python" features (readline support) are wrappers around non-standard C libraries. Is it fair to say that Python has a small library when it uses millions of lines of existing code?

Of course, I really mean CPython. There's Jython (Python-on-JVM), PyPy (Python-on-Python), and IronPython (Python.NET) to name a few; all of them will have their own libraries and no doubt call into C libraries for stuff like file access...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pharo, printing:

```
|i|
i := 0.
SystemNavigation default allBehaviorsDo: [:each| 
each selectors do: [:selector |
    i := i+((each sourceCodeAt: selector) lineCount)]].
i.
```

results in:

- PharoCore-1.1-11326 updated to 11334: 367231
- Seaside-2.8.4: 473368
- Pharo-1.0 with Suixo base framework: 558656
- Seaside 3.0a5: 408019

That includes method comments, and I'm not sure what happens to traits.

Comment: The ideomatic way would be to use inject:into:, but that is not as readable for non-smalltalkers

Answer (score 1):

Probably it should be fairer to compare jQuery with other javascript libraries alike ONLY. I'd like to think that this was taking into account that someone you talk about.

```
jQuery, PRODUCTION (24KB, Minified and Gzipped) or (155KB, Uncompressed Code)
jQuery UI, full Minified 200kb
Prototype, Size: 128kB
Script.aculo.us, Size: 63kB
mootools, Size: 63kB
extJS, Size: 6.6mB FULL, core 130Kb
Yahoo! UI Library (YUI), Size: core minified 17kb, 7kb minified and gzipped, full 379kb minified, 135 minified and gzipped
Mochikit, Size: 380kB
dojo, Size: compressed (27k)
```

Comment: Could you mention # of lines rather then size of file(s)?